# SpringBoot and SpringSecurity Configuration about 404 error page

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with Spring Security and error pages , becaus when I am logged in the application I can show when the page is not exist.

[image]

But when I am out of the application my spring security show the login page by default.

This is my spring security configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
            authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user_login").hasAuthority("USER").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user_login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");


    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

This works correctly but I don't know why when I am out of the application I redirect to login page.

Any solution for this?

Regards!

Comment: Because any request other than / , /login and /registration  needs to be authenticated.  (anyRequest().authenticated())  .  so if you request /abcdef spring will check if authenticated and redirect to login if not. I dont know why do you want to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the requests other than `/`, `/login`, `/registration` requires the user to be authenticated (`anyRequest().authenticated()`), and when you are enabling `formLogin()` spring's filters will redirect all the not authenticated requests to the login page even if the page doesn't exits, thats is why you are redirected to the login and not getting a 404 error.

For testing purposes you can add a test matcher without adding an actual endpoint in the controller like this:
`.antMatchers("/test").permitAll()` and try to access this endpoint without being authenticated and you will get the 404 error page.

p.s. make sure that the 404 response is not blocked as well (if it is a controller response then enable it as well, because your js is allowed for everyone).

Comment: Hello ! I try to solve this problem but I can't find any solution about Spring Filters , can you help to me?

Comment: @jc1992 read the documentation about servlet filters and hot spring is using them, at the beginning it will be a little bit confusing but you will understand it eventually. And read more about the HttpSecurity object, it will help you understand your problem.